# how to iterate over two sets of data?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, posix

I'm trying to create my own program to do a recursive listing: each line corresponds to the full path of a single file. The tricky part I'm working on now is: I don't want bind mounts to trick my program into listing files twice.

So I already have a program that produces the right output except that if `/foo` is bind mounted to `/bar` then my program incorrectly lists

```
/foo/file
/bar/file
```

I need the program to list just what's below (EDIT: even if it was asked to list the contents of `/foo`)

```
/bar/file
```

One approach I thought of is to `mount | grep bind | awk '{print $1 " " $3}'` and then iterate over this to `sed` every line of the output, then `sort -u`.

My question is how do I iterate over the original output (a bunch of lines) *and* the output from `mount` (another bunch of lines)? (or is there a better approach) This needs to be POSIX (EDIT: and work with `/bin/sh`)

Comment: Pipe the output of that line to `while read ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the 'mount | grep bind' command into the AWK within a BEGIN block and store the data.
Something like:

```
PROG | awk 'BEGIN{ 
               # Define the data you want to store
               # Assign to global arrays
               command = "mount | grep bind"; 
               while ((command | getline) > 0) {
                  count++;
                  mount[count] = $1;
                  mountPt[count] = $3
               }
          }
          # Assuming input is line-by-line and that mountPt is the value
          # that is undesired
          { 
              replaceLine=0
              for (i=1; i<=count; i++) {
                 idx = index($1, mountPt[i]);
                 if (idx == 1) {
                   replaceLine = 1;
                   break;
                 }
               }
               if (replaceLine == 1) {
                 sub(mountPt[i], mount[i], $1);
               }
               if (printed[$1] != 1) {
                 print $1;              
               } 
               printed[$1] = 1;    
           } '
```

Where I assume your current program, PROG, outputs to stdout.

Comment: I edited the OP -- added that it needs to work with `/bin/sh`. From what I understand, I can't use arrays like that. Also added an edit that `/foo` should result in a listing of `/bar` (the target) not `/foo`

Comment: The arrays are part of awk's standard functionality.
To give a more precise answer, I would need to see some sample outputs showing the problem areas.
However, the fundamental idea of reading the command's output into an array would remain the same.

Comment: Modified the AWK code to replace `/foo` with `/bar` if found and to only print `/bar` once if both `/foo` and `/bar` are found.
Easier to use if the AWK portion of the code if placed in a separate script file.

Answer (score 1):

```
find YourPath -print > YourFiles.txt
mount > Bind.txt

awk 'FNR == NR && $0 ~ /bind/ {
        Bind[ $1] = $3
        if( ( ThisLevel = split( $3, Unused, "/") - 1 ) > Level) Level = ThisLevel
        }
     FNR != NR && $0 !~ /^ *$/ {
        RealName = $0
        for( ThisLevel = Level; ThisLevel > 0; ThisLevel--){
           match( $0, "(/[^/]*){" ThisLevel "}" )
           UnBind = Bind[ substr( $0, 1, RLENGTH) ]
           if( UnBind !~ /^$/) {
              RealName = UnBind substr( $0, RLENGTH + 1)
              ThisLevel = 0
              }
           }
        if( ! File[ RealName]++) print RealName
        }

   ' Bind.txt YourFiles.txt
```

- search based on a exact path/bind comparaison from a bind array loaded first
- Bind.txt and YourFiles.txt could be a direct redirection to be "1" instruction and no temporary files
- have to be adapted (first part of awk) if path in bind are using space character (assume not here)
- file path are changed live when reading, compare to an existing bind relation
- print file if not yet known